# change several frames in a function in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to solve the below problem

I have the below code. I need to insert several data frames and apply the change at once

```
def reverse_df(*df): 
    for x in df:
        x=x.loc[::-1].reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    return

reverse_df(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)
```

I am able to do changes to a dataframe inside a function only when i am using inplace=True like in below

```
def remove_na(*df): 
    for x in df:
        x.dropna(axis=0, how='all',inplace=True)
    return 
remove_na(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)
```

buy the below doesn't work

```
def remove_na(*df): 
    for x in df:
        x=x.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
    return 
remove_na(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want to `return df`?

Comment: return df is not necessary, it doesnt change anything in my case. I jsut want the changes to be applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: `x = x.dropna(axis=0, how='all')` inside a function creates a local variable called `x`, so the reference to the original dataframe is lost, and any changes you make are not applied.

---

To solve the particular case of reversing the dataframe you can do:

```
def reverse(df):
    df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
    df.set_index('index', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

However, since [inplace operations are not really inplace](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html), you're probably better off returning a modified dataframe.

Comment: This is what I thought. But is there any way to apply the changes when there is no 'inplace' parameter?

Comment: Is it a general question, or just for this case (`.loc[::-1]`)?

Comment: I am mostly interested in this case, but it is useful to know how we can apply a fix in general

Comment: It is interesting to note that the below worked for another function i have  x['samp1']=((x.index +temp )/ 5 + 1) .astype(int)

Comment: In this case you add a column to the dataframe, so the original dataframe is modified.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, with addition of this at the end    x.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)